# How to get ratings Migrate from sharepoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: migration, rating, content-rating

I migrated a content database from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.  I noticed that a particular list which had ratings setup was migrated successfully but the ratings did not migrate (everything seems to be not rated).  Is there a way how i can migrate also the ratings in order to keep the data as it was in 2010.

Comment: did you migrate the USer Profile Dbs as well? i am sure it will works once you migrate the User profile.

Comment: Hi, I was looking at this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719(v=office.15).aspx which describes what you have just said.  Is there a way this can be done without migrating the meta data db and user profile db, such as custom tool or powershell or code?

Comment: I am not usre any tool help this, because this is Social Data sync with UPA.